# R - Merging many columns into one with kind of value checking mechanism

Tags: r

Could you guys please help me with this easy (obviously not for me) thing in R. I have a `data.frame` with many columns with the same values and i need only one column. And additionally also a kind of value checking. Like this:

```
id gender_1 gender_2 gender_3
1    male    male
2    female           male
3                     female
4            male
```

to:

```
id gender_new 
1    male    
2    conflict           
3    female
4    male
```

i tried `coalesce`, `merge`, `join`(without trying to check values between columns):

```
data <- data.frame(id=1:4, gender_1 = c("male","female","",""), 
gender_2 = c("male", "","","male"), 
gender_3 = c("","male","female","")) 

data$Gender_new = coalesce(data$gender_1,data$gender_2, data$gender_3)
```

but it`s not what i really need. As a first step it is sufficient for me without the checking part, but it would be verry useful.

Thank you!

Comment: Edit your post to include the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every row remove the blank values and count number of unique values, if they are more than 1 return `'Conflicted'` or else return the unique value in the data.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  transmute(id, 
            Gender_new = {
              x <- c_across(starts_with('gender'))
              tmp <- x[x != '']
              if(n_distinct(tmp) > 1 || length(tmp) == 0) 'conflict' else unique(tmp)
            })

#    id Gender_new
#  <int> <chr>     
#1     1 male      
#2     2 Conflict  
#3     3 female    
#4     4 male
```

Comment: wow, thank you! if i use the code with my real data i got this error message: <br/> Problem with `mutate()` input `Gender_new`.  <br/>
x Input `Gender_new` can't be recycled to size 1.  <br/>
i Input `Gender_new` is `{ ... }`.  <br/>
i Input `Gender_new` must be size 1, not 0.  <br/>
i Did you mean: `Gender_new = list({ ... })` ?  <br/>
i The error occurred in row 1.  <br/>
I don´t know how to deal with this.<br/>

Comment: @KTTRLD There might be certain rows in which all the values are empty. (`''`). Try the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `pmap`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
data %>%
    mutate(across(starts_with('gender'), na_if, '')) %>%
    transmute(id, Gender_new = pmap_chr(select(., -id), ~ {
      tmp <- na.omit(unique(c(...)))
      if(n_distinct(tmp) > 1) 'conflict' else tmp}))
# id Gender_new
#1  1       male
#2  2   conflict
#3  3     female
#4  4       male
```

---

Or in `base R` with `apply`

```
lst1 <- apply(data[-1], 1, function(x) setdiff(na.omit(unique(x)), ''))
data$Gender_new <- unlist(replace(lst1, lengths(lst1) > 1, "conflict"))
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(id = 1:4, gender_1 = c("male", "female", "", ""
), gender_2 = c("male", "", "", "male"), gender_3 = c("", "male", 
"female", "")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: thank you for your input! @Ronak Shah solved the question for me.